# Как обрезать регулярным выражением конец строки начиная со знака если он встретился последний раз

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, строки, oracle, plsql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT my_scheme.my_package.my_func ('param1', 'param2', int_param3) AS her FROM DUAL
```

который возвращает:

```
р-н Московский, п. Первомайский, ул. трактористов, д. 10, п. 11, ящ. 32123
```

Мне нужно обрезать `, ящ. 32123` . Кол-во запятых *до* может быть разным, всегда надо обрезать начиная с последней запятой.

Answer (score 4):

Если задача стоит как отрезать кусок начиная с последней запятой, то регулярка тут не обязательна. 
Можно сделать например так:

```
substr(s, 1, instr(s, ',', -1) - 1)
```

Comment: То есть получится `select substr(my_scheme.my_package.my_func ('param1', 'param2', int_param3), 1, instr(my_scheme.my_package.my_func ('param1', 'param2', int_param3), ',', -1) - 1) from dual` , а нельзя ли это как-то укоротить, чтоб не повторять дважды?

Comment: @user225775  `select substr(s, 1, instr(s, ',', -1) - 1) from (select my_scheme.my_package.my_func ('param1', 'param2', int_param3) s from DUAL)`

Comment: @Mike спасибо, хороший вариант, но дело в том, что на самом деле у меня селект эдак в ~200 полей и делать из него ещё один селект - нельзя, нужно как-то это уместить в один селект но проще, если возможно

Comment: @user225775 Тогда да, регуляркой проще, написал ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо за потраченное время на меня!

Answer (score 4):

```
select regexp_replace(str,'(.*),.*','\1') from DUAL
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за потраченное время на меня!

Comment: @user225775 вместо спасибо есть кнопочка, принять ответ как правильный

Answer (score 4):

Так покороче и более понятно:

```
select regexp_replace(str, ',[^,]*$') from (
    select 'р-н Московский, п. Первомайский, ул. трактористов, д. 10, п. 11, ящ. 32123' str 
    from dual
);
```

> р-н Московский, п. Первомайский, ул. трактористов, д. 10, п. 11